# How to wire tap a message channel in java dsl?

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying Java dsl in spring integration. I am trying to wiretap a channel. But getting error,

```
@ContextConfiguration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApplication.class);
    CustomGtwy service = ctx.getBean(CustomGtwy.class);
    service.pushMessage("Manoj");

  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel loggerChannel(){
      return MessageChannels.direct().get();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel pushAssetIdChannel() {
       return MessageChannels.direct()
                  .interceptor(new WireTap(loggerChannel()))
                  .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow pushAssetIdFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from("pushAssetIdChannel")
          .handle(new GenericHandler() {
            @Override
            public String handle(Object arg0, Map arg1) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return "Success";
            }})
          .get();
  }

  @MessagingGateway
  public interface CustomGtwy{
      @Gateway(requestChannel="pushAssetIdChannel")
    String pushMessage(String s);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow logger(){
      return IntegrationFlows.from("loggerChannel").handle(new GenericHandler() {
        @Override
        public String handle(Object arg0, Map arg1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return "Success";
        }}).channel("nullChannel").get();
  }
}
```

In the above code, if i try to put message in the pushAssetIdChannel, i am getting `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'`

If the interceptor is not there, it is working.

Comment: Share, please, which version of Java DSL do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going on with your case, but that works for me with the latest `1.0.2` version:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class SO31348246Tests {

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel pushAssetIdChannel;

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        this.pushAssetIdChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public MessageChannel loggerChannel() {
            return MessageChannels.direct().get();
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageChannel pushAssetIdChannel() {
            return MessageChannels.direct()
                    .interceptor(new WireTap(loggerChannel()))
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow pushAssetIdFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from("pushAssetIdChannel")
                    .handle(System.out::println)
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow logger() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from("loggerChannel")
                    .handle((p, h) -> {
                        System.out.println(p);
                        return p;
                    })
                    .channel("nullChannel")
                    .get();
        }

    }

}
```

I see both `SOUT`s in logs.

**UPDATE**

Your class works for me after fixing `@ContextConfiguration` to the normal `@Configuration` annotation :-).

Without the last one the framework considers your `DemoApplication` as **lite** configuration, just because you have there `@Bean` methods, but it does not do it like the **full** one and doesn't proxy it to allow to use `bean method reference` like  you do with `loggerChannel()` in the `WireTap` constructor. 
So, with `lite` we jsut invoke that method and get a fresh `MessageChannel` object, but it isn't a bean in the application context. That's why you end up with the `Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

Comment: I have edited my question above with my whole class file. This gives me the error, not sure the difference..

Comment: thank you it works. Can you please explain what happened inside?

Comment: See the last paragraph in my answer